# Displaying text before product title

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.3.2

I want to add a text "Dragonfly" right before the product Title "Thai Jasmine Rice"

[image]

I have used the code below but it's still below the Product Title what am I doing wrong?

```
<referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.attribute.brand" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute/brand.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Is my answer working for you?

Comment: I'm very new to Magento so I'm lost on which folder I should go to when you say "Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" or "Learning\SetProductName\Model"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is somewhat what worked for me

```
<move element="product.attribute.brand" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title"/>

<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />
```

Answer (score 1):

After listeners are used when we want to change values returned by an original method or want to add some behavior after an original method is called.
We will use after listeners to change the behavior of the getName method of `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.

This method returns the name of the Product.

Original Method is

`public function getName()`

create `di.xml` file and paste the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="learning_magento" type="Learning\SetProductName\Model\Product" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Now create file Product.php in folder `Learning\SetProductName\Model`.
After the listener is called by adding prefix ‘after’ to the method name and setting the first letter of the original method to capital.
Now method and product will become `afterGetName`.

```
<?php
    
    namespace Learning\SetProductName\Model;

    class Product
    {
        public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result) {
            return "XYZ ".$result; // Adding XYZ name to before the product name
        }
    }
```

perform the required commands to view the changes.